# how to re-install Xcode 4.5?

Tags: xcode4.5

My Xcode is not working properly I have downloaded from apples website.It show following error message.Basically i want to re-install Xcode as my current version having some bugs.

[image: Error Message]

What is safest way to re-install Xcode ?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove everything by opening a terminal and typing

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

(You will need su access)

Then go to the App Store -> Categories -> Developer Tools -> xCode and install.

Source: http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/20/uninstall-xcode/